# Random Missing Characters on Ubuntu + Unity + External Display

Tags: unity, video, hdmi, external-monitor

Every time I try to use an external display with my HDMI port I'm having random missing characters on the applications and menus like this:

[image]

Video card on my system:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics [8086:161e] (rev 08)
```

This is my `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` content (485 lines):
http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/10707253/

Output of `unity_support_test -p`:

```
OpenGL vendor string:   Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) HD Graphics 5300 (Broadwell GT2) 
OpenGL version string:  3.0 Mesa 10.3.2

Not software rendered:    yes
Not blacklisted:          yes
GLX fbconfig:             yes
GLX texture from pixmap:  yes
GL npot or rect textures: yes
GL vertex program:        yes
GL fragment program:      yes
GL vertex buffer object:  yes
GL framebuffer object:    yes
GL version is 1.4+:       yes

Unity 3D supported:       yes
```

Comment: I'm getting this problem without an external display. I have a `Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics (rev 09)` video card. The glxinfo is `OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) HD Graphics 5500 (Broadwell GT2)` `OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 10.3.2
`