# Kubuntu 16.04 and 18.04: Suddenly random characters are missing (blank)

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, kubuntu, 18.04, fonts

I have a (stable for years) Kubuntu 16.04 installation VERSION="16.04.4 LTS (Xenial Xerus)"

Recently, I set up for the first time a second user account, and used "new session" to switch to the other user. On the second user's login screen, below the password field, the button said `E t   rren` (or similar) where it should read `Entsperren` (German for unlock). So some glyphs are missing.

Also, the clock misses some digits:

[image]

Please note that the date should read `08.05.18`, so the first digit zero is rendered, the second is not. I can adjust the toolbar height thusly resizing the clock pixel by pixel, and random digits keep disappearing and reappearing, but only when the have the approximate size showing in the screenshot. E.g. reducing the height lets the date appear normal but the time digits disappear.

Additional note: resizing the toolbar and thus the font size makes other random characters vanish, but restoring the size lets always **the same**
characters disappear. E.g. in the example above shrinking the date font 1 pixel lets it display `0 .  .18`, adding 1px again and it displays `0 . 5.18`again.

I have tried to reproduce this using LibreOffice trying to select a font that might by used by the clock, but could not find any rendering problem.

Also, only a few applications seem to show the problem, among them the welcome screen and the clock widget.

I have never seen this problem before switching to another user's session for the first time.

Rebooting now keeps showing the problem, even when I never activate another user session.

---

Not sure if it is linked to
[Random Missing Characters on Ubuntu + Unity + External Display](https://askubuntu.com/questions/603179/random-missing-characters-on-ubuntu-unity-external-display)
or [How to fix display issue where random characters are missing?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/326142/how-to-fix-display-issue-where-random-characters-are-missing)
however at least the font and size appears alike.

---

Update: I installed Kubuntu 18.04 and (while not showing up at the beginning) it also sports the missing characters problem:
[image: missing characters in a notification]

So it seems reasonable that maybe the graphics card driver may be the problem (it is the same version 390 in both Kubuntu versions):

```
$ dpkg -l | grep nvidia
ii  libnvidia-cfg1-390:amd64                        390.48-0ubuntu3                             amd64        NVIDIA binary OpenGL/GLX configuration library
ii  libnvidia-common-390                            390.48-0ubuntu3                             all          Shared files used by the NVIDIA libraries
ii  libnvidia-compute-390:amd64                     390.48-0ubuntu3                             amd64        NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-compute-390:i386                      390.48-0ubuntu3                             i386         NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-decode-390:amd64                      390.48-0ubuntu3                             amd64        NVIDIA Video Decoding runtime libraries
ii  libnvidia-decode-390:i386                       390.48-0ubuntu3                             i386         NVIDIA Video Decoding runtime libraries
ii  libnvidia-encode-390:amd64                      390.48-0ubuntu3                             amd64        NVENC Video Encoding runtime library
ii  libnvidia-encode-390:i386                       390.48-0ubuntu3                             i386         NVENC Video Encoding runtime library
ii  libnvidia-fbc1-390:amd64                        390.48-0ubuntu3                             amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL-based Framebuffer Capture runtime library
ii  libnvidia-fbc1-390:i386                         390.48-0ubuntu3                             i386         NVIDIA OpenGL-based Framebuffer Capture runtime library
ii  libnvidia-gl-390:amd64                          390.48-0ubuntu3                             amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES GLVND libraries and Vulkan ICD
ii  libnvidia-gl-390:i386                           390.48-0ubuntu3                             i386         NVIDIA OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES GLVND libraries and Vulkan ICD
ii  libnvidia-ifr1-390:amd64                        390.48-0ubuntu3                             amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL-based Inband Frame Readback runtime library
ii  libnvidia-ifr1-390:i386                         390.48-0ubuntu3                             i386         NVIDIA OpenGL-based Inband Frame Readback runtime library
ii  nvidia-compute-utils-390                        390.48-0ubuntu3                             amd64        NVIDIA compute utilities
ii  nvidia-dkms-390                                 390.48-0ubuntu3                             amd64        NVIDIA DKMS package
ii  nvidia-driver-390                               390.48-0ubuntu3                             amd64        NVIDIA driver metapackage
ii  nvidia-kernel-common-390                        390.48-0ubuntu3                             amd64        Shared files used with the kernel module
ii  nvidia-kernel-source-390                        390.48-0ubuntu3                             amd64        NVIDIA kernel source package
ii  nvidia-prime                                    0.8.8                                       all          Tools to enable NVIDIA's Prime
ii  nvidia-settings                                 390.42-0ubuntu1                             amd64        Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
ii  nvidia-utils-390                                390.48-0ubuntu3                             amd64        NVIDIA driver support binaries
ii  xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-390                   390.48-0ubuntu3                             amd64        NVIDIA binary Xorg driver
```